# Why round value is different?

Tags: javascript, c#, math

I know if I round up -1.5, it's -2.

so I tried to do with C# it returns -2 correctly.

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(-1.5, 0));
```

also I tried to do with Excel, it also returns -2.

```
=Round(-1.5,0)
```

but when I do with javascript, it returns -1.

```
Math.round(-1.5)
```

why this values are different?

and how can I get -2 instead of -1 when I do this with javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Math.round(Math.abs(-1.5));
```

your value is negative that's why it gets -1. Just get the absolute value and then round it and multiply it to -1 to get -2.

Comment: This seems much better. thanks for answering my question :)

Answer (score 2):

yes round in javascript works as you said. One solution is convert your negative number to positive then use Math.round. At last you should convert your number to negative number.

```
function myFunction() {
  num = -1.5;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.round(num);
  if(num < 0)
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = -1 *  Math.round(Math.abs(num));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's just how they made it. It is acknowledged that it is different than most languages.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

> If the fractional portion of the argument is greater than 0.5, the argument is rounded to the integer with the next higher absolute value. If it is less than 0.5, the argument is rounded to the integer with the lower absolute value.  If the fractional portion is exactly 0.5, the argument is rounded to the next integer in the direction of +∞.  Note that this differs from many languages' round() functions, which often round this case to the next integer away from zero, instead giving a different result in the case of negative numbers with a fractional part of exactly 0.5.